# Python Missing queue (Queue) module, MAVProxy

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run mavproxy.py on OpenSUSE 13.2 but unfortunately I get the following error

```
# mavproxy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/mavproxy.py", line 12, in <module>
import serial, Queue, select
```

> ImportError: No module named 'Queue'

I have found a lot of information concerning the prerequisite for mavproxy and what the Queue module is doing, but I was unable to get usable information on what I have to "pip" in order to download the queue (Queue) module. (pip install queue (or Queue) just fails).

Comment: Is this python version 3? I think Queue as provided by standard lib in python has been harmonized into lowercase queue module ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was theoretically a python 3 file, however with a big number of not upgraded code.... By using import queue and patching the relevant it started to run.